# Non-standardised central limit theorem

Tags: standard-deviation, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $(X_n)_{n}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. Let $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$.

The usual central limit theorem ensures that $\sqrt{n}(S_n/n - \mu)$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. This is often used to motivate the heuristic approximation that $S_n/n$  approximatively follows a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ distribution.

Is there a way of using the central limit theorem (or something else) to actually control how close $S_n/n$ is to $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$?

For instance, would it be possible to assess the convergence speed of $|F_n - G_n| $ to zero, where $F_n$ is the cumulative distribution function of $S_n/n$, and $G_n$ is the one of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$?

Comment: See [Berry−Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem).

Comment: Thanks! It seems it also involves the standardised sum rather than just $S_n/n$, but I guess you can get from one to the other by some change of variable.

Comment: Yes. For instance, $\Phi\bigl((x-\mu)\frac{\sqrt n}\sigma\bigr)$ will be the c.d.f. of $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.